# Why is my mesh separating from my topology with simple deform modifier?

Tags: mesh, modifiers, topology

I'm using a simple deform modifier. I'm not sure what exactly is happening here. Basically when I adjust the angle it's separating from my mesh. Anyone know how to fix this?[image]

Comment: i just can assume, but i think it behaves that way, because the mesh isn't connected. To prevent this, you could e.g. make a knife cut to your "big" model and merge the vertices to your stairs.

Comment: I did try to separate it from my big object previously, that's helpful thank you I'll give that a try